# 'int' object is not iterable : When I try to insert data in Cassandra using Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am facing some issue while inserting data to a Cassandra Table using Python.

Code:

```
session.execute(
    """
    insert into test.student(Student_id)
    values(%s)
    """,
    56)
```

Error:

```
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2239, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2279, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2343, in cassandra.cluster.Session._create_response_future
  File "cassandra/query.py", line 897, in genexpr
  File "cassandra/query.py", line 897, in genexpr
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any other ORM in python, the second argument of `.execute` must be a tuple or a list when using positional arguments:

```
session.execute(
    """
    insert into test.student(Student_id)
    values(%s)
    """,
    (56,))
#     ^ note the parenthesis and the REQUIRED trailing comma
#       to make this a single-element tuple
```

This is also mentioned in Cassandra's [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/getting_started/#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries):

> Note: you must always use a sequence for the second argument, even if you are only passing in a single variable
>
> ```
> session.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (%s)", "blah")  # wrong
> session.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (%s)", ("blah"))  # wrong
> session.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (%s)", ("blah", ))  # right
> session.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (%s)", ["blah"])  # right
> ```